# Writing a macro to swap the values of two symbols

Tags: macros, clojure

I can't think of any possible use case for this, but as an exercise to try to wrap my mind further around Clojure's macros, I'm trying to write a macro that will swap the values assigned to two symbols.

Here are two things that I tried:

Method 1:

```
(defmacro swap [x y]
  `(let [tmp# ~x]
     (def x ~y)
     (def y ~tmp#)))
```

Method 2:

```
(defmacro swap [x y]
  `(let [tmp# ~x]
     (alter-var-root #'x (fn [] ~y))
     (alter-var-root #'y (fn [] ~tmp#))))
```

Here is the code I use to test it:

```
(def four 4)
(def five 5)

(swap four five)

(printf "four: %d\nfive: %d" four five)
```

Expected output:

```
four: 5
five: 4
```

However, using either version of the macro, I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: tmp# in this context`. Am I using auto gensym incorrectly?

Using method 1, I was able to get it to run by changing the last line to `(def y tmp#)))` (taking out the `~` before `tmp#`), however I get the output `four: 4\nfive: 5` which is not swapped.

Comment: Hint: use `(macroexpand-1 '(swap four five))` to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that mutating vars like this is a bad idea, let's assume you really want to do it anyway. Your problem is two-fold:

- You have an unquote on `~tmp#`, where you just want `tmp#`
- You're missing an unquote on `x` and `y`: you want to `(def ~x ~y)` and `(def ~y tmp#)`

The version you wrote always assigns to the vars named `x` and `y`, instead of modifying the vars provided by the user.

Comment: A-ha! That fixed it. Thanks! On a semi-related note, to get the `alter-var-root` version to work, I had to change the `alter-var-root` lines to, e.g. `(alter-var-root (var ~x) (fn [_#] ~y))`. Not only was I improperly unquoting my intermediate gensym var `tmp#` and not unquoting `x` and `y`, but my anonymous function had the wrong arity.